# How to efficiently move the decimal point in a number until reaching some threshold

Tags: algorithm, math, performance

Say I have a double x, whose value is > 0 and < 1 million. I want to move its decimal point left until it is > 1 million and < 10 million. So for example, 23.129385 becomes 2313938.5.

What I'm doing now is just multiplying by 10 until reaching the stopping condition. However I'm performing this algorithm a lot so if I can optimize it somehow it would be helpful. A constant time solution, irrelevant of the magnitude of x, is obviously ideal but so far I haven't been able to come up with one.

Comment: In short: let k= floor(log_10(x)), then  x * 10^(6-k) is the answer you are looking for.  (log_10 is the base-10-logarithm).

Comment: Considering that there are special x86 instructions to deal with the 2 power scenario (according to a collegue), and that logarithm operations can themselves be expensive, then I can imagine that there are more efficient answers, Remember this question isn't just about solving the problem, but solving it efficiently.

Comment: what programming language do you need this in?

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? What do the numbers mean, and how are they processed after you've basically destroyed information about their magnitude? Are you aware that binary floating point can give you surprising results when you think you work with decimals? Is this point in your code actually your performance bottleneck?

Answer (score 4):

Some languages, such as C++ with [frexp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/frexp/), expose the binary exponent as an integer very cheaply.

If you are so lucky you can have a precomputed lookup table `pow2to10` from the 2k possible binary exponents to the power of 10 that it could be.  Have another lookup table `lookup10` for the powers of 10.  Now your computation looks like:

```
frexp(x , &n);
int i = pow2to10[n];
if (lookup10[i+1] <= x) {
    i++;
}
double result = x * lookup10[i];
```

Now instead of a series of multiplications, you have 3 array lookups, one comparison and one multiplication.  If you are executing this in a tight loop, store `pow2to10` as an array of `short int`, try to trim the ranges to what you need, and the lookups will be in a data structure that can fit in L1 cache.

If you are not so lucky, you can instead of repeatedly multiplying, just compare against an array of known powers of 10.  Be warned that if you've got a high level language, you may find that the overhead of running instructions beats the savings of comparison vs multiply.  It may be tempting to do a binary search to do less lookups, but I would bet on linear search being better because that helps branch prediction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which language or which type of CPU, or how the numbers are distributed (e.g. if most of them are less than 5 but rarely a few are large, or..); however...

The fastest scalar version I can think of (assuming C and modern 80x86 CPUs maybe) is:

```
    // x is between 1 and 999999

    unsigned long x_int = x;        // Integer comparisons are possibly faster
    double multiplier;

    if(x_int < 1000) {
        // x is between 1 and 999
        if(x_int < 100) {
            // x is between 1 and 99
            if(x_int < 10) {
                // x is between 1 and 9
                multiplier = 1000000;
            } else {
                // x is between 10 and 99
                multiplier = 100000;
            }
        } else {
            // x is between 100 and 999
            multiplier = 10000;
        }
    } else {
        // x is between 1000 and 999999
        if(x_int < 10000) {
            // x is between 1000 and 9999
            multiplier = 1000;
        } else {
            // x is between 10000 and 999999
            if(x_int < 100000) {
                // x is between 10000 and 99999
                multiplier = 100;
            } else {
                // x is between 100000 and 999999
                multiplier = 10;
            }
        }
    }
    x *= multiplier;
```

This adds up to 2 or 3 branches and one multiplication per value. *Note: for modern 80x86 the final branch can be replaced with a `CMOVcc` instruction.*

If you're doing this a lot; then the next step would be to try to use SIMD to do multiple values at the same time (followed by multi-threading/multi-CPU).

Comment: This is exactly the approach that I meant when I said, "It may be tempting to do a binary search to do less lookups, but I would bet on linear search being better because that helps branch prediction."

Comment: @btilly: Linear search will make branch prediction worse; either by focusing all the branch history on a single "end of loop branch", or (if it's unrolled) by having far more potentially mispredicted branches. Note that the main reason for my approach (and the `CMOVcc` hint) is that it's hopefully easy to see how it would be modified to work with SIMD (not forgetting OP said they're doing this a lot, so doing 4 at a time with AVX2 will probably make it almost 4 times faster). Lookup tables don't work for SIMD.